# Django admin How to solve the problem that all parts are not visible?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I created a system with Django. I create an abstract user model with some custom fields. My form is working but in the admin page I cannot see my custom models.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    ranks = (
        ...
        ('cfo', 'Chief Financial Officier'),
    )
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Choose")
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ranks)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
...
```

**admin.py**

```
    admin.site.register(CompanyProfile)


class CustomUser(UserAdmin):
    add_form = SignUpForm
    model = UserProfile
    form = SignUpChangeForm
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'email', 'last_name', 'rank', 'comp_name')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
       
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'rank', 'comp_name')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = 'email'


admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserAdmin)
```

[image: admin view]

As you can see in admin view there is no `ranks` and `company name` field. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add them to fieldsets aswell, from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin)

> **Note**:
> If you are using a custom ModelAdmin which is a subclass of django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin, then you need to add your custom fields to fieldsets (for fields to be used in editing users) and to add_fieldsets (for fields to be used when creating a user). For example: